# How to achieve this figma design in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to achieve this Figma design.
I already have tried with `ExpansionTile` widget, but I can't get the same design.

This is the design, left **non** tapped connector, right, **tapped** connector, shows the two connectors.

[image: Figma design]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) Widget [ExapnsionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) Widget for the same. These widgets will help you to achieve this Figma design first you have to make the design of it and then you can use the Visibility and hide/show widget using the visible parameter which will take a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following library: [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable). I recently made a pretty similar screen with it, it's highly customizable :)

Answer (score 0):

this example for your case :
put this value before build widget
 `bool isAnimate = false;`
and then put those widgets out build widget also:

```
Container yourFirstChildWidget (){
    return Container();
  }
  Container yourSecondChildWidget (){
    return Container();
  }
AnimatedContainer yourChildrenWidgets (){
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      curve: Curves.linear,
      width: 373//Assume the whole container that Includes you widget width is 373,
      height: isAnimate ? 80: 80*3, //Assume that 80 is the height of the
      // container, then 3 is the total number of containers,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
      child:  Column(children: [
        yourFirstChildWidget(),
        yourSecondChildWidget(),
      ],),
    );
}
GestureDetector yourPerantWidget (){
    return  // in your peran widget
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isAnimate != isAnimate;
          });
        },
      );
}
```

and after those steps put above widgets in build widget with some modifications

```
  isAnimate ? AnimatedAlign(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: yourChildrenWidgets()) : yourPerantWidget(),
```

*and yahoo! you got it (:*